# How many Smart contracts have been published? how many times have those smart contracts been executed?

Tags: contract-deployment

Does anyone know approximately how many (production) smart contracts are out there and how many times smart contracts have been executed in total? I'm okay with order of magnitude (10,000s, 100,000s, etc.) for my purpose.

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ethereum blockchain explorers out there but some of them seem to agree that there are around 600 dapps on the chain now.

Edit: yeah, I'm lowering the number as I continue looking into it.